# How to implement java tile map lights?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, light

I have a 2D tile map in java (using libgdx no Tiled Map Editor) formed with squares and I want the tiles to gradually become darker until they won't be visible. So basically I don't want round light. The only option I know is to use alpha channel and make every tile from the source which is the player become less visible. I want to know how can I implement this using a shader. I want to render my map normally with a spritebacth and then apply the shader to my spritebacth, so I can render the light effect. Each tile should have it's own visibility. An example of a game which uses the kind of lightning I want is: http://www.desura.com/games/fragile-soul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render each tile itself via `SpriteBatch` and use `spriteBatch.setColor(r, g, b, a)` with different "grey" values.

The tile where your player is standing on will start with white, so `spriteBatch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)` before rendering that one. And then linearly decrease the brightness for the other ones in a radius around.

For example all tiles one next to the player might get `spriteBatch.setColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f)` resulting in a slightly darker tile. You do this until you reach black via `spriteBatch.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1)`. All those tiles will be completely black.

Comment: Wouldn't this consume a lot of resources, resetting the batch's color every frame ?

Comment: Resources? What kind of resources? I think it doesn't force the SpriteBatch to flush, at least it's not documented. I assume it won't be a problem.

Comment: I will try to use this method. If I will consider using more effects than just lights I will look for a shader to render light maps. I found no information about square light maps that is why I asked (because shader for radial blured light is simple, I needed something so only blocks would have been lighted).